# drug and ICD-10 lookup web service for my web app

Tags: web-services, saas, medical

I want to lookup drugs (by name) and ICD-10 codes (by keyword or code) in my web portal. Users will enter keywords and select from an auto-complete list in my portal.

I tried the [MedlinePlus](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/connect/service.html), but I can't seem to get the ICD-10 to work. It also doesn't support lookup by keyword.

```
https://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.90&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=A0101&informationRecipient.languageCode.c=en
```

This query doesn't return any records. In this example, I am trying to look for ICD-10 code "A0101".

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is the api defined?

Comment: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/connect/service.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an output format, JSON, for example;

https://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.90&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=I25.110&knowledgeResponseType=application/json

This example uses JSON and returns results. I've replaced the code A0101 with I25.1.10 that you used. A0101 with the JSON output request shows that 0 results were found, ie- the code is not used. When used with my example, the results are returned in the 'entry' subsection of 'feed' array.